# img file pushes down to hover. how could i properly appear hover on image and place hover

Tags: html, css

Screenshot:

[image]

img file pushes down to hover. How could I properly appear hover on image and place hover on image?

```
<div class="colunm5">
        <img src="images/picture1.jpg">
        <p class="colunm5_centered">aaaa</p>
    </div>

.colunm5 {
    width:340px;
    height:378px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom:155px;
}

.colunm5_centered {
    width:340px;
    height:378px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.colunm5_centered{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.colunm5:hover .colunm5_centered {
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
visibility:visible;
```

}

Comment: A demo would be more useful that the somewhat broken code you have provided.

Comment: Impossible to understand the actual question. A working code would be a great starting point...

Comment: where's you're hover css ? I presume you're talking about the paragraph appearing when you hover the image, is that correct ?

Comment: .colunm5 {
 width:340px;
 height:378px;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 display:inline-block;
 position: relative;
 bottom:155px;
}

.colunm5_centered {
 width:340px;
 height:378px;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.colunm5 img {
 float:left;
}

.colunm5_centered{
 visibility: hidden;
}
.colunm5:hover .colunm5_centered {
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 visibility:visible;
}

Comment: Html <div class="colunm5">
  <img src="images/picture1.jpg" width="340px" height="378px">
  <p class="colunm5_centered">aaaa</p>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear, but I guess that you want the partially transparent p to appear in the same location as the image, overlapping it, is that right?
In that case, all you need to do is position the p absolutely, since its parent is already positioned relatively.

```css
position: absolute;
left: 0; top: 0;
```

Snippet:

```css
.colunm5 {
  width: 340px;
  height: 378px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 155px;
}
.colunm5_centered {
  width: 340px;
  height: 378px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.colunm5:hover .colunm5_centered {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="colunm5">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w571.png">
  <p class="colunm5_centered">aaaa</p>
</div>
```

Please note that I had to change the image URL to have something we can see.

Comment: Does this answer solve the problem? If so, could you mark this as correct by clicking the check mark to the left. That way, it will no longer turn up in the list of unsolved questions.